# Apply Function on all rows to get a matrix output in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, dataframe, apply

I need to apply a function on all the rows of the dataframe. This parameters for these function will be two vectors,

For example,

```
f <- function(vec1,vec2)
     { return(sum(vec1) - sum(vec2))
     }
```

Now I need to apply this on all the rows of my dataframe, so that I can populate all values in a matrix and use that matrix for my analysis.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),B=c(3,4,3,4),C=c(5,6,4,5))
```

Applying this function should give the following matrix

[image]

Comment: `mapply(FUN = function(m,i){return(sum(m[i[1],]) - sum(m[i[2],]))},
       m = replicate(nrow(df)^2, df, simplify = F),
       i = data.frame(t(expand.grid(1:nrow(df), 1:nrow(df))))); matrix(.Last.value, ncol = 4)` Akrun's solution is better. Wrote it so commenting it.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi not yet looked into the solutions or comments please let me go through and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m <- diag(nrow(df))
s <- rowSums(df)
r <- combn(nrow(df), 2, function(x) c(s[x[1]]-s[x[2]],s[x[2]]-s[x[1]]))
m[lower.tri(m, diag = F)] <- r[1,]
m <- t(m)
m[lower.tri(m, diag = F)] <- r[2,]
diag(m) <- 0

     # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0   -3   -1   -4
# [2,]    3    0    2   -1
# [3,]    1   -2    0   -3
# [4,]    4    1    3    0
```

In case you insist to use you own defined function `f`, do this:

```
m <- diag(nrow(df))
r <- combn(nrow(df), 2, function(x) c(f(df[x[1],],df[x[2],]), f(df[x[2],],df[x[1],])))
m[lower.tri(m, diag = F)] <- r[1,]
m <- t(m)
m[lower.tri(m, diag = F)] <- r[2,]
diag(m) <- 0
```

Comment: I have a different function ( user defined) and the rows and columns cannot be hard coded